# Sed script to to rewrite certain strings

Tags: regex, sed

I'm dealing with a body of XML files containing unstructured texts with semantic markup for personal names.

For reasons to do with the stylesheet that will eventually show them via a web application, I need to replace:

```
<persName>Fred</persName>'s
<persName>Wilma</persName>'s
```

with

```
<persName>Fred's</persName>
<persName>Wilma's</persName>
```

I have a single line in a shell script, being run in Gitbash for Windows, below. It runs OK, but has no effect. I suppose I'm missing something obvious, perhaps to do with escaping characters, but any help appreciated.

```
sed -i "s/<\/persName>\'s/\'s<\/persName>/g"  test.xml
```

Comment: Try `sed -i "s,</persName>'s,'s</persName>,g" test.xml`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, this works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -i "s,</persName>'s,'s</persName>,g" test.xml
```

**Details**

- `s` - we want to replace
- `,` - a delimiter
- `</persName>'s` - this string to find
- `,` - delimiter
- `'s</persName>` - replace with this string
- `,` - delimiter
- `g` - multiple times if more than one is found

The `-i` option makes the replacements directly in the file.

Note that you do not have to escape `'` when defining the sed command inside a double quoted string.

It is a good idea to use a delimiter char other than the common `/` if there are `/` chars inside the regex or/and replacement pattern.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, easy to understand :), i tried using backslash `/` , didn't get the correct result.

Comment: There's no need to write `</persName>` twice and you don't need the `g` given the sample input so it can be just: `sed -E -i "s,(</persName>)'s,'s\1" test.xml`

Comment: @ed, will need to escape the backslash within double quotes: `'s\\1`

Comment: Y'know I thought about that.... Thanks. I'd personally write it as `sed -E -i 's,(</persName>)'\''s,'\''s\1' test.xml` as I hate exposing any more of a script than necessary to the shell for interpretation but didn't want to muddy the watres.

Answer (score 1):

The comment on your question suggests an easier solution, but I guess, that there might be names where the suffix `'s` differs, like names ending with an `s`. So I chose a solution where you grab what's right and put it in the middle.

As separator for the search and replace command in sed you can choose whatever you want. I've chosen `#`, so you don't have to escape the backslashes in the text. The escaped parantheses store what's inside in variables `\1` and `\2`.

```
sed 's#<persName>\(.*\)</persName>\(.*\)#<persName>\1\2</persName>#g' testfile
```

Result:

```
<persName>Fred's</persName>
<persName>Wilma's</persName>
```

If you want to replace it in file, you can use the `-i` parameter. But be sure to check the result first.

Comment: Thanks for this. The other answer works well enough for me, but I now understand that one can choose whichever separator one wants: this was what I had not grasped.